# asp.net check if email exists when registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to check whether my email is existed while registration,so I used remote in my model like this.

```
[DisplayName("Email")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "請輸入Email")]
        [Remote("EmailCheck", "Member", ErrorMessage = "has already exist")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTPO6.jpg)
and my EmailCheck in Service

```
 public bool EmailCheck(string Email)
    {
        Member Search = db.Member.Find(Email);
        bool result = (Search == null);

        return result;
    }
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv9E1.png)
but Search returns null even if I have exactly the same email in my database already .Can someone figure this out?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please when you refer to code, this code should be included in your post. It's a bit difficult for the readers of your post to go back and forth between you post and your links. Thanks :)

Comment: is the 'string Email' have the right value (maybe it is posted from the browser incorrectly?)